# SCP is very slow

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, scp

I am renting dedicated server in a leaseweb and trying to transfer tar files from leaseweb's server to my HOME NAS, but the problem is - max upload speed i get is 180kb/sec, though when i try to upload file from my HOME NAS through SCP to leaseweb's dedicated server, the speed is about 4-5mb/sec.

So i expect the same 4-5mb/sec for upload from leaseweb -> to my HOME Nas. What could be the issue? I am using BusyBox 1.22 on my Home NAS.

Comment: Try running a speed test (e.g., speedtest.net or similar) from the server itself. Maybe it has an asymmetric connection or something.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you have the following situation:

```
(unknown method) leaseweb -> home NAS (180kb/sec)
           (scp) home NAS -> leaseweb (4-5mb/sec)
```

This looks like an asymmetric connection to me. Perhaps leaseweb has a bandwidth cap outbound, but no bandwidth cap inbound? That seems most likely.

My advice is to run speed tests between both machines (you can use FTP or netcat) and remove scp from the equation. This is because it's actually harder to get SCP to get decent speeds, and requires more introspection into each environment. Bandwidth tests are relatively simple.

Should you find that it is, in fact, SCP that is the issue...remember with SCP that you have two essentially independent configuration domains for each direction:

```
 Host A                Host B
 ------                ------
 scp(client)        -> sshd (running on B)
 sshd(running on A) <- scp(client)
```

So from Host A to Host B you need to look at the SSHD configuration on B and the SSH configuration on A. However, from Host B to host A you need to look at the SSHD configuration on A and the SSH configuration on B. Each direction can be configured differently, and hence give you asymmetric performance.

Comment: I just tested with DigitalOcean now, got the same trouble. So i suspect it's my Home NAS? (note: when i am uploading trough NCFTP i am getting 4-5mb sec, it's only with SCP). Also i am using BusyBox 1.21 on my NAS

Comment: It's an assumption of course, albeit a reasonable one. I get real skeptical when I find things like this and check all the configuration files. I'd certainly agree to start with your HomeNAS. Can you find the sshd_config file on it?

Comment: I don't see sshd_config under /etc/ssh/. Where else it could be located?

Comment: When i am uploading to my NAS (My NAS has 25-75% Cpu load) maybe that's a culprit?

Answer (score 0):

`ssh` to NAS and then try `scp bigfile user@leaseweb:/bigfile` and then try `scp user@leaseweb:/bigfile bigfile2` to be sure you are measuring the link, not the scp implementation on particular machine.

maybe the scp on leaseweb is crippled somehow

Comment: As i told you in my question - i already did this. Pay attention please on my post above - "though when i try to upload file from my HOME NAS through SCP to leaseweb's dedicated server, the speed is about 4-5mb/sec"

Comment: from the way it's written I understood that you try to upload file from A to B and then try to upload file from B to A. There is 'upload' word twice and no 'download' word at all.

Comment: Well, i just tried to download: Downloading file from Home NAS to Leaseweb is 4-5mb/sec, same with download a file from leaseweb to my home NAS

Comment: well, I am not here to argue with you, I just wanted to help you. Nevermind.